# Sending System Events key down/up using JXA

Tags: javascript-automation

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and was wondering if you could help.

With AppleScript, there are two hidden functions available in the System Events application which allow you to push a key down (keeping it down while other actions, like clicking are done), and then bringing the key back up again.

e.g.  see the answer here [Applescript to run Detect Displays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640643/applescript-to-run-detect-displays) whereby "key up" and "key down" are used while a click is being performed.

But for the sake of this example, let's use something very simple, a Save shortcut.

The AppleScript looks like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key down command
    keystroke "s"
    key up command
end tell
```

The closest I've gotten to this in JXA is as follows, but no matter what I pass to keyDown, it sends the letter "a":

```
events = Application("System Events")
events.keyDown("command")
events.keystroke("s")
events.keyUp("command")
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Fotis

Comment: Never use `key up` / `key down` in `System Events` unless you have no other choice. Here you have: `keystroke "s" using command down`

Comment: As per my post, I only used cmd + s as an example.  The originally aim was to reproduce the AppleScript at the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640643/applescript-to-run-detect-displays which I believe must use key down and up actions as the script clicks a button while the key is held down.  You can see my completed script at https://github.com/fgimian/macbuild/blob/master/detectdisplays.js

Comment: Got it, I just wanted to mention that the usage of `key up` / `key down` is pretty dangerous. If an error occurs while the key is down, it stays down!

Comment: @vadian absolutely agreed!  This is why it's critical to use a try / catch block as I have in my detectdisplay.js script.  I tested this quite thoroughly and confirmed that it works very reliably, but it is indeed dangerous without exception handling.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, the solution was tricky to find but I've got it :)

You may use the special strings eCmd (command), eOpt (option) and eCnt (control) to accomplish this as defined in SystemEvents.h.

As such, the following code works!

```
events = Application("System Events")
events.keyDown("eCmd")
events.keystroke("s")
events.keyUp("eCmd")
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
events = Application("System Events")
events.keystroke("s", {
    using:"command down"
});
```

Have a nice day, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Appreciate the response, and this would indeed be a better way to implement the code I posted.  However, as per my post, I was attempting to reproduce the AppleScript at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640643/applescript-to-run-detect-displays and only provided my Cmd + s script as an example to simplify my question.